# Error in plugin MAD scorecard on Android Studio 4.1.1, not working

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I am installing the recent plugin MAD scorecard on Android Studio. When I launch it, it displays the following error:

> Error during MAD scorecard generation: There has been an error in the
> generation of your mad scorecard java.net.UnknownHostException:
> madscorecard.withgoogle.com

[image: error plugin mad scorecard]

Comment: yes still **404 Not Found** in 11/2022. I enjoyed this plugin

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using it for a long time, it didn't work when I installed the plugin in the new version `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1` and tried it.

[image]

Deprecated based on recent comments:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15549-mad-scorecard/reviews